# HTML / CSS Padding for <section> isn't working

Tags: html, css

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vVFW.jpg)The padding in the section that will contain the content of the page goes from end to end with no space from the edge.

HTML:

```
<section>
    <heading>
        <h2>Welcome to Funky Munky!</h2>
    </heading>
    <article>
        <p>
            New in Cedar City, UT
        </p>
    </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1% 0;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: #f5c300;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you give screenshot/illustration what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box` :

```
section {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1% 0;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: #f5c300;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Without that, the 2% padding on each side is added to the 100% width of the box, so it has a total width of 104% and is thus larger than the page.

**Update**

Since you've posted an image of the problem, it seems that you want some spacing between the edge of the page and the box itself. Is that correct?

If it is, change the margin to `margin: 1%` instead of `margin: 1% 0`. Then, change the width to 98% (100% - 1% on each side).

As you have it set now, there's a 1% margin above and below the element, but no margin to the left and right of it.

The padding is for the inner spacing (spacing between the edges of the box and the content inside it), margin is the space between the edge of the box and the other elements outside.

Comment: I have the box-sizing: border-box; at the top of my CSS under *{}. I tried it your way and it still didn't fix it. I see the problem with 2% padding and 100% width but it worked in other elements of mine... hmmm.

Comment: I've updated my answer, is this what you want to do?

Comment: So I did what you said and I got a space from the left side but the right side is still connected to the edge. Could this be from the padding that is set?

Comment: @AnthonyHulett Set the width to 98% (I've updated my answer again). Your element is 102% wide without that.

Comment: Good! You can accept this answer if it fixed your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
section {
    width: 98%;
    margin: 2% 2%;
    padding: 0%;
    background-color: #f5c300;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 
width to 94%
margin: 1%

so that 1% of space will be gone for margin on each side(2%)
and for padding 2% on each side (4%)

Therefore,
width = 100 - 2 - 4 = 94%

```css
section {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: #f5c300;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <heading>
            <h2>Welcome to Funky Munky!</h2>
        </heading>
        <article>
            <p>
                New in Cedar City, UT
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
```

Comment: You don't need to account for the 4% of padding if you're using `box-sizing: border-box` (which he is), only for the margin. ;)

Comment: Yes. If box-sizing is used, we don't have to worry about padding

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the "orange" box to have some space around it.

The issue here is that the padding setting exists "within" your section. In other words, the spacing from the edge that it creates will all be within the orange box. The contents of the box, however, will be forced inwards, away from the edge.

If you want white space around the outside of the box, I suggest changing the margin to 1% 1% (the second 1% is for your left and right side)...or some higher number for more space and lowering the width by the margin% X 2 + (padding%*2).  In this case, width will be 88% (to allow for 1% space on either side).

like this:

```
width: 88%; /* padding x2=10 + margin*2 = 2 */
margin: 1% 1%;
padding: 5%;
```

This fiddle demonstrates this using two margin and padding settings that yield the same sized box.
https://jsfiddle.net/wkaskie/wdarLbpt/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could accomplish the same effect by adjusting your width to mimic the presence of padding/margin. Just remove left/right padding and center the section with margin auto:

```
section {
width: 96%;
margin: 1% auto;
padding: 2% 0;
background - color: #f5c300;
opacity: 0.7;
color: #000;
text-align: center;
```

}